# How to define ng-options selected value and assign this to model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model, ng-options

I have a data like this which i compile to select options and inside it selected value defined as `defaultValue: 1`

```
content: [
    {
        value: "Bireysel",
        key: "1",
        defaultValue: 0
    },
    {
        value: "Kurumsal",
        key: "2",
        defaultValue: 1
    },
    {
        value: "Bireysel & Kurumsal",
        key: "3",
        defaultValue: 0
    }
]
```

I can convert this to select opitons and send user's selected value to server.

```
<select ng-model="model.customer" ng-options="item.key as item.value for item in model.properties['CUSTOMER']" name="customer" required>
</select>
```

But when i try to define selected value i can not send to server. I've tried 
`track by` but it selects all option fields and i can not send selected field to server.

---

```
<select ng-model="model.customer" ng-options="item.key as item.value for item in model.properties['CUSTOMER'] track by defaultValue" name="customer" required>
</select>
```

---

I've also tried `ng-repeat` not `ng-options`. This method seems dirty, it selects default value true but i can not send true data to server if user isn't changed any option. This occurs because of `ng-selected` is not assigns default value to my model: `model.customer`

```
<select ng-model="model.customer" name="customer" required>
    <option ng-repeat="item in model.properties['CUSTOMER']" value="{{item.key}}" ng-selected="item.defaultValue">{{item.value}}</option>
</select>
```

**How can i manage to define default value using `ng-options` and assign this to my model for sending true data to server ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value of your model can be set with ng-init, like this :

```
<select ng-model="customer" ng-init="customer = content[0].key" ng-options="item.key as item.value for item in content" name="customer" required>
```

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/13874/)

Comment: i need to define selected value according to defaultValue, if its 1 it shoul be selected.

Comment: Thank you very much +1 from me. One more last question, how can i convert this function to dynmaic for using it on muliptle select boxes, example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/13876/

Answer (score 0):

```
var CONTRIBUINTE = -1,
        IMOVEL = -2,
        ECONOMICO = -3,

     $scope.tiposConsulta = [
        { Id: CONTRIBUINTE, Descricao: 'Contribuinte' },
        { Id: IMOVEL, Descricao: 'Imóvel' },
        { Id: ECONOMICO, Descricao: 'Econômico' }];

$scope.tiposConsultaSelected = CONTRIBUINTE;


<select id="tipoConsulta" class="btn form-control"
                        ng-model="tiposConsultaSelected"
                        ng-options="tipo.Id as tipo.Descricao for tipo in tiposConsulta">
                    </select>
```